# Unable to locate an element with puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

I'm trying to do a basic search on FB marketplace with puppeteer(and it was working for me before) but fails recently.
The whole thing fails when it gets to "location" link on marketplace page. to change the location i need to click on it, but puppeteer Errors out saying:

> Error: Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement

If i try to get the boundingBox of the element it returns null

```
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const resp = await page.goto('https://www.facebook.com/marketplace', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })
    const withinLink = await page.waitForXPath('//span[contains(.,"Within")]', { timeout: 4000 })
    console.log(await withinLink.boundingBox()) //returns null

    await withinLink.click() //errors out
```

If i take a screenshot of the page right before i locate an element it is clearly there and i am able to locate in in chrome console using the same xPath manually.
It just doesn't seem to work in puppeteer

Something clearly changed on FB. Maybe they started to use some AI technology to detect scraping?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to archieve?

Comment: @Lukas I need to open "Change location" dialog to set my location correctly

Answer (score 1):

I don't think facebook changed in headless browser detection lately, but it seems you haven't taken into account that `const withinLink = await page.waitForXPath('//span[contains(.,"Within")]', { timeout: 4000 })` **returns an array,** even if there is only one matching elment to `contains(.,"Within")`.

That should work if you add `[0]` index to the elementHandles:

```js
const withinLink = await page.waitForXPath('//span[contains(.,"Within")]')
console.log(await withinLink[0].boundingBox())
await withinLink[0].click()
```

*Note:* Timeout is not mandatory in waitForXPath, but I'd suggest to rather use `domcontentloaded` instead of `networkidle2` in `page.goto` if you don't need all analytics/tracking events to achive the desired results, it just slows down your script execution.

*Note 2:* Honestly, I don't have such element on my fb platform, maybe it is market dependent. But it works with any other XPath selectors with specific content.

Comment: According to this: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v4.0.0/docs/api.md#pagewaitforxpathxpath-options waitForXPath returns an event handle(unlike $x(...)). so if i do "withinLink[0]" it'll just return "undefined".

Comment: Yeah, true. However, the click will work like this as well (I've never tried it earlier, just adopted your existing code). The official solution should be indeed `const withinLink = await page.$x('//span[contains(.,"Within")]')`. For me both works the same.